# Partial deserialization and serialization in Java?

Tags: java, performance, serialization

There are a huge number of libraries and approaches out there to serialize and de-serialize objects in Java. 
What I would like to do involves rather large and complex objects which need to get sent back and forth between processing nodes.

However, each node only is interested in one or a few, usually small parts of the whole object. The processing node processes that part and creates a new part that would need to get spliced into the existing serialized object before it gets sent on.

For this, two things would be of high importance:

- being able to just deserialize parts of the serialized object (and thus save parsing/deserialization time, object creation time, memory...) and to also add the serialization of some new part to the existing serialized object (again saving time and memory) -- skipping the unwanted parts in the serialized version should be extremely fast and efficient and should ideally be possible in a streaming mode, without the need to keep the whole serialized data in memory at once
- overall compact and fast serialization and deserialization.

I am pretty flexible as to how much automation I get for actually creating typed objects versus untyped maps and lists: if all else fails I would be able to represent the whole object as a nested data structure of just maps, arrays and the basic datatypes boolean, String and Number.

UPDATE: forgot to mention two additional, rather important requirements:

- the solution must be possible with the existing objects, i.e. it is not possible to re-implement the current object using a e.g. different collections class.
- ideally the solution should be based on open-source software because the software I need this for will be published itself as open-source.

Comment: Is it possible to decompose a complex object into parts and serialize that individual parts?

Comment: Have you looked into externalization?

Comment: There is a number of libraries which allow you to use serialized objects in place extracting or updating just the fields you are interested in. Chronicle Byte/Wire, SBE, Javolution struct.

Comment: @Vince Emigh: Externalization, as far as I understand basically solves the problem at compile time, and for one specific subset of the data, but I need to be able to do this at run time, and for multiple subsets for the same object: if i send the object to node A, I want to see part1 and part2 of the object and add partA and node B may want to access part3 and add partB1 and partB2.

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you're planning a design where a whole bunch of data is sent to a processing node, and that node will only read/modify/write a small part of it.  But then will send the whole bundle on to another node.

Why not have the host that has all the data figure out which node needs which data, and only send that data?  Then processing can happen in parallel, instead of daisy-chain.  And your total network traffic will be less than every node sending a full copy of everything: O(n*m).

It might be worth designing your own message format, potentially based on JSON, binary, or something else.

Comment: That is not possible because only the processing node will know which part it wants to look at and which part it wants to add. The actual size of the data is not really the problem, but the complexity is: de-serialization of the full object would take a lot of time simply because there may be millions of small nested parts to unpack, but the majority of those are irrelevant to the node.

Comment: @Johsm: hmm.  IDK what to suggest if you really want to keep using standard serialization/deserialization, other than an extra round trip: Server tells node what it wants to node to do.  Node asks for a specific part of the data set.  Server sends it, etc. etc.

Comment: TBH I would have thought that the requirement to only look at part of a serialized object would have been more common so that a standard solution exists. If not, I will accept cooking my own, but it would be a pity to re-invent an existing wheel.

Comment: @Johsm: for partial deserialization to be efficient, you'd need some kind of index, wouldn't you?  Otherwise the receiver still has to parse all the serialized data, just not create objects from it.  IDK, there *might* be a way to do this with some standard APIs.  I don't know how, but I'm not an expert.  I just answered to suggest an even more efficient solution.  Hopefully that didn't scare off answers from people with more experience with seralization APIs/libraries.

Comment: I think what I am after is a simple approach to "skip" the deserialization of unwanted objects or, on serialization, a way to just add another object to an existing complex, already serialized data structure. For example, if the object is a map, I may be interested in only the object for a single key in that map, leaving thousands of other objects (which may each be quite complex) unparsed. I think with many (binary) serialization formats that include lengths, it should be very easy to skip over the unwanted entries in the map and only deserialize the one entry I am interested in.